# Docker-compose with nginx is not mounting volume

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've a docker-compose which setting up an nginx with a react static site.
When I'm running up the docker-compose I'm trying to sahre with the container a folder which contains my ssl certificates, but the nginx is not able to find them.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: frontend
    image: colymore/frontend:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/colymore.me/:/certs/:ro    
    labels:
      - com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true
    networks:
      net:
```

In the nginx confi I've

```
ssl_certificate /certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /certs/privkey.pem;
```

And the file exists:

```
colymore@colymore.me$ ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/colymore.me/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/colymore.me/fullchain.pem
```

But when IO run the ngins it's giving an error:

```
52a5118c5c40_frontend | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/certs/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/certs/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Comment: What's your host OS?

Comment: Ubuntu inside a vps